# How to catch org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException with status code and return personality response in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

Good afternoon, I am currently working with Apache Camel and Quarkus for the first time and I am calling an API that returns different types of http code, when it returns an http code other than 200, I get an exception of the following type:

```
org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://10.162.128.94:30000/customerInformation/v1.4.0/users/CI-2056133/customers with statusCode: 404
```

The idea here is to be able to catch this exception and the corresponding http code to return a response of the following type with http code 404:

```
{
    "code": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "A specified resource is not found"
}
```

My code is the following but I don't know how to configure it to capture the error, I know that the main exception is **HttpOperationFailedException**:

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.route;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.beans.response.UserProfile;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.UserProfileProcessorHttpCode404;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.UserProfileReq;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestParamType.body;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ResRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @ConfigProperty(name="client.findCustomerByDocId")
    String findCustomerByDocId;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "path.openapi")
    String openApiPath;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "descripcion.servicio")
    String serviceDescription;

    private ConfigureSsl configureSsl;

    public ResRoute() {
        configureSsl = new ConfigureSsl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .apiContextPath(openApiPath)
                .apiProperty("api.title", "FindCustomerByDocId")
                .apiProperty("api.description", serviceDescription)
                .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");

        rest("userProfile/v3.7/users/")
                .get("/{user_id}").to("direct:/{user_id}")
                .outType(UserProfile.class)
                .param().name("UserProfile").type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true)
                .endParam()
                .to("direct:pipeline");

        from("direct:pipeline")
                .doTry()
                .process(new UserProfileReq())
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq())
                .setHeader("x-correlator",constant("4242374781"))
                .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findCustomerByDocId))
                .choice()
                .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo(404))
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessorHttpCode404())
                .otherwise()
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes())
                .endChoice()
                .endDoTry()
                .doCatch(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorHttpCode404());

    }
```

With the previous code I tried to do it, but it does not throw me anything, it returns a code 204 and it should return a response like the one I referred to above, I attach my code of the UserProfileProcessorHttpCode404 class:

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.processor;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.beans.response.UserProfileResponseFault;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.mapping.IUserProfileOpenApiResponseFaultMapping;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.mapping.impl.UserProfileOpenApiResponseImpl;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;


@ApplicationScoped
public class UserProfileProcessorHttpCode404 implements Processor {

    private String errorCode404 = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("error.404.code", String.class);
    private String errorMessage404 = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("error.404.message", String.class);
    private IUserProfileOpenApiResponseFaultMapping responseFault;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public UserProfileProcessorHttpCode404() {
        responseFault = new UserProfileOpenApiResponseImpl();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        UserProfileResponseFault openApiResponse = responseFault.toFault(errorCode404, errorMessage404);
        String jsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(openApiResponse);
        exchange.setProperty("bodyRs", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonResponse));
        exchange.getMessage().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        exchange.getMessage().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 404);
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(jsonResponse);


    }
}
```

What should I do in these cases? Should the response code filtering be done within the doTry or doCatch?